# Update with function called once for each row in Postgres 8.4

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, sql-update

I have the following UPDATE statement:

```
update mytable
   set a = first_part(genid()),
       b = second_part(genid()),
       c = third_path(genid())
 where package_id = 10;
```

In this example the function `genid()` is called three times for each row, which is wrong - I want it to be called only once for each row of `mytable`.

I'm using PostgreSQL 8.4 database. How to write the correct update?

I've tried something like this:

```
update mytable
   set a = first_part(g),
       b = second_part(g),
       c = third_path(g)
 where package_id = 10
  from genid() as g;
```

But it didn't work, because `genid()` has been called only **once** for the whole update statement.

Comment: Can't you put that in a stored procedure and first call `genid()`, store it in a variable and then use it in your update statement?

Comment: you simplified too much the example, I ques you have gen_id(column)

Comment: @Florin No, genid takes no parameters, it generates a unique value on each call, based on an arbitrary sequence and random generator. That's why I want it to be called once for the each row of the mytable.

Comment: Looks like there is already a working solution in the answers, but is defining an additional column for the full `genid` + a row-level trigger that updates a, b and c on insert/update of that column an option?

Comment: Additional column is not an option, we have about 2000 such tables, and the schema is rather constant. This column would be too much overhead for millions of records.

Comment: @Cezariusz can you try with a cursor? as I suggested in my updated answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you tried Postgres' non-standard `UPDATE .. FROM` clause? I imagine, this would work

```
update mytable
   set a = first_part(gen.id),
       b = second_part(gen.id),
       c = third_path(gen.id)
  from (
          select genid() as genid, id
          from mytable 
          where package_id = 10
       ) gen
 where mytable.id = gen.id;
 --and package_id = 10 -- This predicate is no longer necessary as the subquery
                       -- already filters on package_id, as Erwin mentioned
```

Note that I'm forcing `genid()` to be called exactly once per record in `mytable` within the subselect. Then I'm self-joining `mytable` and `gen` using a hypothetical `id` column.
See the documentation here:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-update.html

<s>This seems to have been introduced with Postgres 9.0 only, though.</s> If that seems too complicated (i.e. not very readable), you can still resort to pgplsql as user [Florin suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8677481/update-with-function-called-once-for-each-row/8677518#8677526).

Comment: This works great, thanks. I have some performance concerns, though, because of the hash joins this involves.

Comment: The second `where package_id = 10` is redundant. The subquery already filters (as it should). If `mytable.id` is indexed (as it should be), the redundant check is of no use.

Comment: @Cezariusz: Have you analysed the execution plan? If you self-join on primary keys, the join should be fairly efficient.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: You're right. I hadn't thought about it that way. I'll fix it

Comment: +1 Now I like your answer. :) You should probably link to the manual for version 8.4 (OP's version) or the current version. Preferably to the `/interactive` branch. [Consider this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108714/best-way-to-reference-the-postgresql-manual).

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: Nice link, I wasn't aware of "/current" documentation sub-paths. They're usually not the ones found on google... :) btw: You can edit answers too, if you feel something should be improved (e.g. a link)

Comment: @LukasEder: When dealing with experienced users like you I only edit when I am 100% certain and rather default to a comment. The high reputation tells me you generally know what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if this is working in postgres?

```
update 
  (select 
     a, b, c, genid() as val
  from mytable
  where package_id = 10
  )
set a = first_part(val),
       b = second_part(val),
       c = third_path(val);
```

**Update:**
just for the ideea: Can you try it with a cursor?

```
DECLARE c1 CURSOR FOR 
      select 
         a, b, c, genid() as val
      from mytable
      where package_id = 10; 
...
UPDATE table SET ... WHERE CURRENT OF c1;
```

Comment: Doesn't work with **any** version of PostgreSQL, a.k.a. "wrong answer".

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use following -

```
DECLARE @genID VARCHAR(100) -- or appropriate datatype

SET @genID = genid() -- Or select @genID = genid()    
update mytable    
   set a = first_part(@genID),
       b = second_part(@genID),
       c = third_path(@genID)
where package_id = 10;
```

Comment: That's probably the path of least resistance, compared to my rather verbose solution... (if pgplsql is allowed in this case)

Comment: In this case `genid()` will be called only once for the whole table update, am I right? I need it to be called once for each row.

Comment: Yes that will be called only once for whole table update. And in your case I think User Lukas has suggested most appropriate way to achieve this.

Comment: That won't work with PostgreSQL (you cannot declare variables like that)